# Email Piping with Express.js / Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, piping, mean-stack

I am planning a web application that I would like to utilize email piping with. I am primarily a PHP developer, but I'm learning MEAN stack development with Node.js and Express to do this project.

I have done alot of digging and can't really find any good tutorials or resources to figure out how to do email piping in node.js. I'd like some advice on how to do this if anyone has a good answer.

The situation i'm looking at is, I add a contact to the application with name, email, etc and then someone emails me and the system intercepts that email and if I have a contact with that email address, it goes under their account. Similar to how basecamp or highrise or a host of other applications would allow you to pipe emails to a contact or project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was doing some additional digging and I found this NPM module: https://www.npmjs.org/package/mailparser

Looks to be exactly what is needed for this.